# Vue 3 (Typescript + Class Components + Composition API): How do define Props in the Setup method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-class-components

When using the Composition API with Class Components in Vue 3 and when using Typescript, how can properties be defined in the `setup` method? For example:

```
export default class Test extends Vue {
    myAContext = setup(()=> {...})
    myBContext = setup(()=> {...})
}
```

In this code, I do not want to use the `Options` attribute, and neither would I like to use the `@Prop` attribute that comes in the `vue-property-decorators` package as I believe they are part of the Options API and I think it would not be a good practice to mix these two APIs together.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Edit:
To better clarify, how can I define Props that are scoped to the context (setup method lambda)?

Comment: It's not possible to declare props from the `setup()` hook.

Comment: @tony19: When using the vue-class-components, does that library use composition api or option api?

Comment: @tony19: I mean does the Options attribute mean Option API? The name is a bit confusing. From my perspective (after posting the question), it has nothing to do with the option API.

Comment: Yes, it uses the Options API, and there's no reason to avoid using that API.

Comment: @tony19: Do you mean using the Options API together with the Composition API is not a bad thing?

Comment: The Options API is still required for several features (including declaring components, directives, etc.). The only mix you should avoid is declaring data (including `data`, `props`, `computed`, `methods`) in the Options API and trying to access them from the Composition API, or vice versa.

Comment: @tony19: So in this case, how can I avoid declaring `props` using the Options API?

Comment: You can't. Props can only be declared with the Options API. Since you're using `vue-property-decorator`, stick with that library's semantics, which means use `@Prop` to declare a prop (and this uses the Options API under the hood).

Comment: @tony19: But what if I want to use Composition API as it makes my project cleaner?

Comment: @tony19: I mean I think there has to be a correct way to link props with the composables in this case.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `<script setup>`, and `defineProps`, but you can't use class syntax there. Otherwise, the only way to declare props is with the Options API. Trying to avoid the Options API entirely because of some belief that the Composition API is "cleaner" is severely misguided.

Comment: @tony19: Thank you for helping me. If I would like to stick with the Options API, instead of writing composables I have to create mixins, and I think those cause conflicts sometimes. That is what I mean by a cleaner solution.